# Using R to determine the number of shared logical values across all possible unique dyad combinations

Tags: r, dataframe, social-networking

I have a data frame that contains groups and logical vectors assessing whether they reside in each area.

```
# Create data frame
Group = c('Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3', 'Group4') 
Area1 = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) 
Area2 = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE) 
Area3 = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE) 
Area4 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE) 
df = data.frame(Group, Area1, Area2, Area3, Area4) 

# Generate unique combinations of Groups
links <- expand.grid(df$Group, df$Group) #generates all possible combination
links$key <- apply(links, 1, function(x)paste(sort(x), collapse='')) 
undirected <- subset(links, !duplicated(links$key)) 
undirected$ID <- seq.int(nrow(undirected))
```

For each unique group dyad, I am trying to determine how many areas they share. My desired output is the dyad, the count of number of areas they share, and the names of the areas.

```
# Desired Output
Group1Group2  1 Area2
Group1Group3  1 Area1
Group1Group4  0 NA
Group2Group3  0 NA
Group2Group4  2 Area3, Area4
Group3Group4  0
```

Comment: The basic counts of presence/overlap you can get with `tcrossprod(as.matrix(df[-1]))` - I suspect you might need `igraph` or something else to get the more detailed output.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure that I've understood your question properly. The data structure is confusing. Does the dyad `{i=2, j=4}` titled `Group2Group4` really have Areas 3 and 4 in common? I'd think not.

I'm not sure `igraph` is really needed here. This *could*, however, be set up as a bipartite network like `G(V₁,V₂,E)` differentiating `areas ∈ V₁` from `groups ∈ V₂` and having dyads running always from areas to groups: `eⁱʲ ∈ E; i ∈ V₁; j ∈ V₂`. Then you'd get shared areas by listing each group-node's neighbourhood, and the number of hared areas by counting their in-degree.

If you'd really, really like to see that in code, I'll re-post when I have time.

In the meanwhile This, I think, does what you like. I'm not winning any code-golfing competitions on this one, but if I understand your question correctly, it does the job:

```
# Make that same data
Group = c('Group1', 'Group2', 'Group3', 'Group4') 
Area1 = c(TRUE, FALSE, TRUE, FALSE) 
Area2 = c(TRUE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE) 
Area3 = c(FALSE, TRUE, FALSE, FALSE) 
Area4 = c(FALSE, FALSE, FALSE, TRUE) 
df = data.frame(Group, Area1, Area2, Area3, Area4)

# Take two groups (by number) and list the areas they have in common
is.shared <- function(i, j){
    # Make a dataframe with two rows (one for i and one for j) where
    # The order of the areas are multiplied with the boolean that indicates
    # if the group resides in area x. If so, set x, if not, set 0.
    dyad <- as.data.frame(matrix(rep(2:ncol(df)-1,2), nrow=2, byrow=T)) * df[c(i,j),2:5]
    # The shared areas is the intersection of the two sets
    shared.areas <- intersect(as.numeric(dyad[1,]), as.numeric(dyad[2,]))
}

# Take a vector of area-numbers and return a string that lists them.
# c(2,4,0) becomes "Area2, Area4".
list.areas <- function(vector){
    result = c()
    for(area in vector){
        if(area != 0){
            result <- c(result, paste("Area", area, sep=""))
        }
    }
    paste(result, collapse=", ")
}


# Make a matrix of all possible dyadic combinations (two-way)
dyads <- expand.grid(1:nrow(df), 2:ncol(df)-1)
names(dyads) <- c("Group i", "Group j")
# Each row contains a dyad - a pair (i, and j) of groups.

# Generate a unique dyadic key
dyads$Key <- apply(dyads, 1, function(x) paste(sort(x), collapse='->'))

# For each row of dyads, that is to say, for each pair (i,j), check if
# any areas are shared using is.shared(), and convert the result to a
# string using list.areas()
dyads$Shared_Areas <- sapply(1:nrow(dyads), function(x)
    list.areas(is.shared(dyads[x,1], dyads[x,2]) )
)

# Count the number of shared areas by splitting the string by commas
dyads$Shared_Area_Nums <- sapply(dyads$Shared_Areas, function(x)
    length(strsplit(x,",")[[1]])
    )

# Not that it's not as safe to count the result of is.shared() directly.
# If two groups share ALL areas with each other, no 0 will be returned in
# the vector. If we asume that no two groups reside in all areas, it would
# also be ok to generate dyad$Shared_Areas like this:
dyads$Shared_Areas_Unsafe <- sapply(1:nrow(dyads), function(x)
    length(is.shared(dyads[x,1], dyads[x,2]))
) - 1

# Rename columns
dyads <- dyads[,c("Group i","Group j", "Key", "Shared_Area_Nums",
            "Shared_Areas_Unsafe", "Shared_Areas")]
```

Then go ahead and clean to an undirected structure if you like, and perhaps the auto-links to (I don't get the impression that Group2Group2 is of interest to you).

Note that you had come half-way with your code. Particularly the `expand.grid(df$Group, df$Group)` was neat.